# Transformer Prime, VPN and password protection

Tags: vpn

I have VPN connection on my Android tablet (Asus Transformer Prime) and it required me to set up a password protection for my tablet. I don't want to use any dummy passwords to open my tablet, so how can I disable that without deleting the VPN connection?

Comment: really desperate for a solution to this too. I have a feeling it might be something that needs patching so root would be necessary. Having to unlock my phone is a ball ache, I'd rather have it just ask for a password when I connect to the VPN, typical, non-configurable bad defaults

Comment: Those finding this a nuisance should vote for the bug at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41130 to request a fully supported fix. Especially since the current workarounds are arguably security holes and might be "fixed", leaving us stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this, it's a hack but it works for on my galaxy nexus 2.1.2
Here's the steps:

1. Set your lock screen security to what you want, slide/none
2. Go to create VPN profile
3. Create a pattern lock
4. Setup VPN profile
5. Lock device
6. Unlock but input the wrong pattern until device locks for 30.
7. Tap "Forgotten Pattern"
8. Enter your google account details.
9. Cancel the "Screen Security" page
10. Now device will unlock without pattern requirement

Source: [Connecting to VPN forces having secure screen lock](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22867/connecting-to-vpn-forces-having-secure-screen-lock)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!  It worked on HTC One S, but my tablet doesn't seem to have option to reset the pattern in the lock screen...?

Comment: Sorry, it required the slide protection instead of pin :)

Answer (score 2):

Step #1)
Create security lock through Settings (pattern, pin, password).

Step #2)
Add VPN connections

Step #3)
Plug the phone in and run these commands (requires adb to be setup properly and drivers).  I am sure there is a way to do this directly on the phone but this is easier for me.

Commands to remove security:

```
adb shell
sqlite3 /data/system/locksettings.db
update locksettings set value=0 where name='lockscreen.password_type';
.exit
exit
```

http://www.teambamf.net/topic/4488-guidehow-to-use-vpn-in-jellybean-without-security-lock/

Comment: I did it directly on my (rooted) phone, using the same commands, in a terminal window, using the sqlite3 executable in my http://linuxonandroid.org/ environment. If you don't have sqlite3 on your phone, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645319/why-do-i-get-a-sqlite3-not-found-error-on-a-rooted-nexus-one-when-i-try-to-op You might also try copying the locksettings.db file to your PC and running sqlite3 there. Of course, you need write access to /data/system. Sigh. Let's just say that if you're rooted and have sqlite3 installed, this is the way to go.

Comment: On some devices this settings is in `settings.db`: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/can-not-unlock-my-android-device-as-have-no-internet-connection

Comment: After `set value=0` and reboot my VPN page says: "type the password for credential storage"

Answer (score 1):

Variant 1 - answer by kiiwii with `locksettings.db`

Variant 2 - `settings.db`, `SYSTEM`, `lock_pattern_autolock`

Variant 3 (when there's no `lock_pattern_autolock` in `SYSTEM`):

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db

SECURE

none:
lockscreen.disabled|1
lockscreen.password_type|65536
lock_pattern_autolock|0

slide:
lockscreen.disabled|0
lockscreen.password_type|65536
lock_pattern_autolock|0

pattern:
lockscreen.disabled|0
lockscreen.password_type|65536
lock_pattern_autolock|1

pin:
lockscreen.disabled|0
lockscreen.password_type|131072
lock_pattern_autolock|0

password:
lockscreen.disabled|0
lockscreen.password_type|262144
lock_pattern_autolock|0
```