# Connecting to VPN forces having secure screen lock

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, security, lock-screens, vpn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transformer Prime, VPN and password protection](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21512/transformer-prime-vpn-and-password-protection)

I noticed that creating a `VPN` connection in ICS forces me to use a secure screen lock. I want to have Slide method for my screen lock, but it's disabled when I've set up a VPN connection. Is there a way to use a slide lock with a VPN configured?

> Phone: Google Nexus S
>   OS: Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I found a solution.

I just chose Pattern, turned off the screen, turned it back on and clicked on Forgot in the lower-right corner. After I gave in my Google password it changed automatically back to slide.

In the settings the option "none" is still grayed-out but it's selected anywhere and it works.

Comment: thanks, it worked! but it seems to be a bug, because in privacy settings, Slide and Face unlock is disabled, but my screen lock is Slide.

Comment: There's no "forgot" in in my android 4.0.4 phone

Answer (score 3):

This is for security reasons: If you lose your phone with VPN set up, anyone can log into your network. Having a pin lock mitigates this threat.

If you happen to have CyanogenMod 7+ installed there's an option called **Profiles**. You can setup your *default profile* to have no screen lock at all (not even slide lock). That's the closest I got. Hint: This feature is for things like in car usage where you don't want a lock at all (using your phone while driving is illegal but people still do it).