# How to change lock screen due to VPN settings

Tags: lock-screens, vpn

I just faced this problem.. i turned on my VPN last night and a pop up told me to change my lockscreen settings to either password or fingerprint (I'm using Samsung Galaxy Note 4), so i did. Ever since that, I cant change my lock screen settings back to none.. i have tried deleting all my VPN. I have tried to choose the Clear Credentials option but its grayed out. I have tried entering my google account at the forgot password section on the lockscreen but it shows that i had entered incorrect username or password (but I'm sure of my google account email and password). So what else can i do?

Comment: did you try your google login at a different machine? just to make sure you're not hacked. Also see http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22867/connecting-to-vpn-forces-having-secure-screen-lock?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android for Work? Try this:

1. Go to Settings > Security > Device administrators
2. Deactivate the entry that has installed security policies
3. Now go back and see if you can change your screen lock settings